# cueChange event is getting called many times before TextTrack has changed the currently displaying cues

Tags: javascript

HTTP Live Streaming: I am listening for timed metadata embedded as ID3 tags using Javascript

```js
videoElement.textTracks.addEventListener("addtrack", onAddTrack);

const onAddTrack = function (event) {
  const track = event.track;
  if (track.kind === "metadata") {
    track.addEventListener("cuechange", () => {
      //what you want with the cueChangeEvent
      //Tacking active cue, parsing and displaying
    });
  }
}
```

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/cuechange_event), *"The `cuechange` event fires when a `TextTrack` has changed the currently displaying cues."*

But cueChange is fired before TextTrack changes